# IF..ELSE block not working SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `if else` block in my procedure . The value of a temporary variable **`@timeID`** is set in this block according to today's date.

```
declare @timeId int
if(datename(Dw,getdate())='Sunday' or datename(Dw,getdate())='Saturday')
begin
  set @timeId=2
end

if(datename(Dw,getdate())!='Sunday' or datename(Dw,getdate())!='Saturday')
begin
 if(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),108)<='08:30:00')
  begin
   set @timeId=0
  end
 else
  begin
   set @timeId=1
  end
end


select @timeId as TimeID
```

Since today is **Saturday** , **`@timeID`** must be set equal to 2.
But output shows **`@timeId=1`** which results in wrong result from my procedure. Please help what's wrong.

```
select datename(Dw,getdate())
```

returns Saturday

Comment: I guess the condition `if(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),108)<='08:30:00')` is getting false and `if(datename(Dw,getdate())!='Sunday' or datename(Dw,getdate())!='Saturday')` is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, assume it is Saturday:

The first `IF` block runs.

Then the second `IF` block runs because of the `OR` condition on `!= Sunday`, overwriting `@timeid`.

You want an ELSE (and in fact, you can drop the extra test, simplifying the code):

```
declare @timeId int
if(datename(Dw,getdate())='Sunday' or datename(Dw,getdate())='Saturday')
begin
  set @timeId=2
end

ELSE

begin
 if(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),108)<='08:30:00')
  begin
   set @timeId=0
  end
 else
  begin
   set @timeId=1
  end
end
```

Comment: It works..!!! thanks..but please tell what I was doing wrong .. why second If else block gets executed and @timeid becomes 1

Answer (score 3):

Your second if clause should use AND, not OR.  Every day is NOT Sunday OR NOT Saturday